# how to get Acceleration from Android Motion Sensors at a fixed rate with 1 KHz

Tags: android, android-sensors

I have already tried -  `SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST`
Android `SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST` isn't fast enough
the `SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST` is `200HZ`,Slower than what I want.

I would need a `1000Hz`.

Is there a way of polling the sensors rather than waiting for a `SensorEvent` ?

Comment: I don;t think that the sensor itself supports 1000HZ

Answer (score 2):

Using `registerListener` from the Android [SensorManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html) API, `SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST` will get you the highest data rate supported. However, this rate depends on the device. Most devices will respond to `SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST` with updates around 100 Hz, but on a Nexus 5x and a Pixel 3 I get 400 Hz and I have seen some Samsung flagships with 500 Hz.

However, when using a newer device with at least Android 8 you might be able to squeeze out a bit more using [`SensorDirectChannel`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorDirectChannel.html) introduced with API level 26. This one offers [`RATE_VERY_FAST`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorDirectChannel.html#RATE_VERY_FAST) with rates in the range of 440 Hz to 1760 Hz. Of course, this needs to be supported by the device.